# example of a metric space in which triangle inequality is equality

Tags: metric-spaces

Is there any example of a metric space $X$ with more than two points such that the triangle inequality is always equality?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In any metric space with at least two points, the triangle inequality is an actual inequality. For if $x\neq y$ and thus $d(x,y) > 0$, then by the triangle inequality,
$$
0 = d(x,x) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,x) = 2d(x,y),
$$
and by our hypothesis we must therefore conclude that
$$
d(x,x) < d(x,y) + d(y,x).
$$

Edit: removed some redundancies. The same conclusions hold for a nontrivial pseudometric.

Answer (score 3):

Such an example does not exist ! Suppose that the metric space $X$ contains 2 points $x,y$ with $x \ne y.$

Then we have

$0=d(x,x) < d(x,y)+d(y,x)=2d(x,y)$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps no: $0=d(x,x)=d(x,y)+d(y,x)$; so $d(x,y)=0$ i.e. $x=y$.